# Save attribute into another model when creating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

What would be the best way to approach this problem.

When a user is created in my app you enter an email address which is saved to the user model, what i would like to do is also save that email address to say a Profile model so that I can use it elsewhere within my application. it cant be edited as part of the profile model and will change if the email changes in the User model

Im a little unsure on how to approach this, would an after_create method work for something like this?

As far as syntax goes though Im unsure how to start this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user.rb

```
class User < AR
  after_create :create_profile
  after_update :update_email

  def create_profile
    Profile.create(email: email)
  end

  def update_email
    email_was = previous_changes['email'][1]
    email_is = email
    return nil if email_is == email_was
    Profile.find_by(email: email_was).update_attributes email: email_is)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Models:

```
class User
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  validates_associated :profile
end

class Profile  
  belongs_to :user
  validates :email, presence :true
end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_profile
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(users_params)
    @user.save
  end

  private

  def users_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :profile_attributes => [:email])    
  end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  #other user stuff
  <%= f.fields_for :profile do |builder| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= builder.label :email %>
      <%= builder.text_field :email %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so this will update the user model and the profile model and only have the user enter their email address once ?

Comment: Yep, as you can guess by the name this allows the user to accept attributes for the profile and will then save them to the profile.  `validates_associated :profile` will check to see if the profile is valid and give an error on saving of 'Profile is invalid' if you try and enter something that isn't valid.